# What is the best possible way to Activate/Inactivate a trigger in production without any deployment?

Tags: apex, trigger, customsetting

I have many triggers in my org which needs to be deactivated for few reasons during deployment. I was going through google and found at few places that this can be done with the help of 'Hierarchy Custom Setting' and few lines of code in each trigger. We will need to only change the custom setting value to true/false to activate/inactivate a trigger. The issue I am facing is that nowhere I am able to find a proper approach of how to do it. I went through the below site but still did not get the full idea of how to achieve this.

https://www.sundoginteractive.com/blog/disabling-triggers-in-production-dynamically

Please suggest me full approach of doing this.

Comment: My would suggest instead of hierarchy custom setting use list custom setting.. there create all the records for your trigger.. and in trigger check related  object's custom setting value if true or false

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would suggest instead of hierarchy custom setting use list custom setting.. there create all the records for your object's trigger.. and in trigger check related object's custom setting value is true or false

### Example for Account Trigger

Create a custom setting with 2 fields

1. Name (No need to create by default exist)
2. Create a boolean variable (isTriggerActive)

Now create a record like name= Account and isTriggerActive = true

And create a trigger on Account

```
trigger AccountTrigger on Account (before insert, before update) 
{
  Custom_Setting__c objCustomSetting= Custom_Setting__c .getInstance('Account');
  if(objCustomSetting.isTriggerActive == false)
  { 
    return;
  }
  // rest trigger code here
}
```

if `objCustomSetting.isTriggerActive` is false then below code will not execute

and `objCustomSetting.isTriggerActive` is true then it will not enter inside if condition means return statement will not execute and it will execute rest of the code

---

### Updates

If you have multiple trigger on single object(This is not best practice always try to create single trigger per object) and you just want to disable any one of them

Then I suggest go with artifacts name approach

In custom setting

For example on Account you have 2 trigger `AccountTrigger` and `AccountTrigger 1`

Now you want to disable `AccountTrigger` trigger

So like above create a custom setting and create 2 records for `AccountTrigger` and `AccountTrigger 1`

```
--------------------------------------------------
|     Name            | isTriggerActive |
--------------------------------------------------
|  AccountTrigger     |    true         |
--------------------------------------------------
| AccountTrigger1     |    true         |
--------------------------------------------------
```

and in trigger

```
 trigger AccountTrigger on Account (before insert, before update) 
    {
      Custom_Setting__c objCustomSetting= Custom_Setting__c .getInstance('AccountTrigger');
      if(objCustomSetting.isTriggerActive == false)
      { 
        return;
      }
      // rest trigger code here
    }
```

So if you disable the `isTriggerActive` for AccountTrigger then rest code will not execute

Comment: Or we can put the condition like this `if(objCustomSetting.isTriggerActive == true)` and can put all code inside condition no need of `returrn;`

Comment: @itzmukeshy7 yes we can do that.. I just don't want to add all the complete huge code inside a if condition

Comment: @sfdcweb : As per the example its can be done for object. But what if I have 2 trigger on a particular object and I want to deactivate only 1 ? I know it is best practice to have only one trigger per object. But as per my situation I need to have one trigger which needs to run only once for record updates in production and then will never be run. To do deployments faster I need to activate/deactivate it instantly so that other records are not affected in the mean time.  Is it possible to achieve this with trigger name wise instead of object wise ?

Comment: @Ruchi then I suggest instead `objectName` in custom setting go with artifacts name(Trigger Name) so for each trigger you have a custom setting Name and `isTriggerActive` boolean.. this way you can handle for each artifacts.. Let me know if this make sense to you

Comment: ok...I will try your suggestion. Thanks a lot for your help. :)